# Is there a way to connect to Spotify api without installing its own app?

Tags: java, android, api, spotify

Is there any way of using the actual Spotify Api for Android without installing Spotify app?

I'm trying to build a custom "mini-social-network" with Spotify integrations like your favorite genres or a top 5 all-time songs , for example.

Not so much time ago, the entire API changed and I don't really know if I need to obligate the users to install Spotify and my app separately. I'm using the Spotify SDK and the doc page says that it is necessary to install it.

Thanks for checking out.